# Migrate to the Play Install Referrer API Unity3d

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, admob

I received message today from google play

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We recently announced that we’ll be deprecating the install_referrer intent broadcast mechanism. Because one or more of your apps uses this intent to track referrals, we wanted to ensure you make the switch before March 1, 2020. After this date, new versions of the Play Store app will no longer broadcast the install_referrer intent after app installs.
>
> Action required
>
> Migrate to the Play Install Referrer API to track your app installs for the following apps and/or games.

I am using unity3d and my project have (Firebase & AdMob ), but i don't know what can i do because this libraries from google!

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is the following permission added to merged manifest by either your Admob or Firebase

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.finsky.permission.BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE" />
```

For Firebase you should probably stay tune to next Firebase update from Google, but if you have only Admob in your project and you are using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0` in your build Gradle ,update to `18.3.0` (or later) then re-build and verify if this permission is removed from merged-manifest (generated in your build folder) in your Intermediate folder!

Comment: Thank you, And every play-services-ads is 18.3.0 but there is some libraries 17.0.0
like :
com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-17.0.0 
com.google.android.gms.play-services-stats-17.0.0
com.google.android.gms.play-services-measurement-17.2.1

What do think delete every libraries then install again !

Comment: Can you please tell a little bit more? I have no idea where is the build Gradle and Intermediate folder is. And how to update to 18.3.0. I am using official AdMob plugin for Unity in Unity 2019.1.8f1 and Unity analytics. I am so confused right now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I **analyzed** my debug **APK**, I saw `INSTALL_REFERRER` inside the receiver of `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver`. I attached the SS below.

[image]

So, I added the following code in my project `AndroidManifest.xml` to remove it. That solved my issue.

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Hope this helps for someone. Thank you.